# how to train a custom object detection model ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco and ssd_inception_v2_coco on google colab tensorflow 1.15.2?

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, nvidia, object-detection-api

Basically I have been trying to train a custom object detection model with ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco and ssd_inception_v2_coco on google colab tensorflow 1.15.2 using tensorflow object detection api. As soon as I start training it throws error for both the models respectively.

I also ran the `python object_detection/builders/model_builder_tf1_test.py` and it passed all the test without any errors or warnings.

`ValueError: ssd_inception_v2 is not supported. See` model_builder.py `for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow.`

`ValueError: ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco is not supported. See` model_builder.py `for features extractors compatible with different versions of Tensorflow.`

I have successfully changed the tensorflow to 1.15.2 by using below command this is my first step before installing any of the dependencies.

```
%tensorflow_version 1.x
import tensorflow
print(tensorflow.__version__)
```

When I checked the model_builder.py I can see that they still have support for ssd_mobilenet_v1 and ssd_inception_v2. I want to deploy my custom trained model ssd_mobilenet_v1 or ssd_inception_v2 on jetson tx2 by converting them into trt-tf models
. In these 2 documents https://www.elinux.org/Jetson_Zoo and https://github.com/NVIDIA-AI-IOT/tf_trt_models#od_models we can see object detection models which can be converted to tf-trt models. So my question is how can I train these models as they are supported on google colab on tensorflow 1.15.2 and deploy on jetson txt for converting them to tf-trt models? Can anyone guide me through it would be really helpful to conitue my learning and learn something interesting thanks

Answer (score 0):

i think you downloaded both of the models from tensorflow v2 repository and tensorflow 1.15 will obviously not support them.
download models from here : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md
and try again.good luck

Comment: I downloaded from https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/research/object_detection/g3doc/tf1_detection_zoo.md 
Not sure what's the issue but I am still trying to find out I have found couple of exmaples of colab where they are running tf1 models on google colab tf1 version